# GAE Region - Exact Location

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud, gsutil

My GAE (Standard) app is hosted in europe-west region.

I am looking into creating a Cloud SQL instance in support of this app and would like to place it closest to the GAE.

Current Cloud SQL instances are available at below locations:
europe-west1    Belgium 
europe-west2    London
europe-west3    Frankfurt

Is there any way to find out additional location details of my GAE app in order to decide which Cloud SQL location to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gcloud app describe` from the cloud shell in order to find out your app's location info. Typing this command (gcloud app describe) in the shell returns something like this:

```
authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.my-project-id.appspot.com
defaultBucket: my-project-id.appspot.com
defaultHostname: my-project-id.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
gcrDomain: eu.gcr.io
id: my-project-id
locationId: europe-west2
name: apps/my-project-id
servingStatus: SERVING
```

See the command description [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/regions/list).

Next you can create your SQL instance by typing `gcloud sql instances create [your-instance-name] --region=[region-of-your-choice]`. For example:

```
user-id@my-project-id:~$ gcloud sql instances create test-instance --region=europe-west2
Creating Cloud SQL instance...done.
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project-id/instances/test-instance].
NAME           DATABASE_VERSION  REGION        TIER              ADDRESS         STATUS
test-instance  MYSQL_5_6         europe-west2  db-n1-standard-1  00.000.000.000  RUNNABLE
user-id@my-project-id:~$
```

All the available options are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/create).